# Tracking hyperlink usage in Microsoft Word

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, usage-statistics

Is it possible, using Google Analytics or a Word feature, to record what hyperlinks a reader follows when s/he is reading a Word document on a web page?

Comment: How you would read a word document on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like goo.gl or bit.ly to shorten the URLs. It offers some analytics capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear what you mean by reading a word document on a web page. Do you mean embedded word doc or simply a web page?

If you have access to the Word doc on the page, you could implement a unique UTM code to the linked URL(s), which should show up in your GA reporting.

Otherwise, you could see within GA source/medium reporting which website the visitor was referred from. If the source matches the website with the word doc, you can assume the visitor clicked the link. If there are multiple links on that web page, however, you won't be able to determine which exact link the visitor clicked.

Comment: To clarify, I want to give web access to a MS Word document which, inside, will have a number of links. Is there any way to record which links a particular reader followed, either by means inside MS Word, or by website reporting? Thanks for your help.  ... LA